# canvas.getZoom() is undefined in Angular8 using fabricjs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I am using `fabricjs` in Angular 8 and on mouse wheel event, I want to zoom the canvas. But, when the event is triggered, I got the error about the function, `canvas.getZoom()` is `undefined`. I have searched but, I didn't get anything related to this issue. My other functionality in the `fabricjs` is working, but this isn't.

Here is my code :

```
  this.canvas.on('mouse:wheel', function(opt) {
    var delta = opt.e.deltaY;
    console.log("delta",delta)
    var zoom = this.canvas.getZoom();
    console.log("zoom",zoom)
    zoom = zoom + delta/200;
    if (zoom > 20) zoom = 20;
    if (zoom < 0.01) zoom = 0.01;
    this.canvas.setZoom(zoom);
    opt.e.preventDefault();
    opt.e.stopPropagation();
})
```

It prints on the console with the value of delta, but after `this.canvas.getZoom()` fires, it throws error.

Comment: `this` inside the function is the function itself, not the component. You can try to solve it by declaring a `self = this` outside that function, and use `self.canvas.getZoom()`

Comment: I am using Angular 8 and "this" is the reference to  canvas global variable

Comment: self doenot  exist on type "Window&typeof globalThis'

Comment: Then if this inside the function is the canvas itself just use `this.getZoom()`

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback